# Is there a replacement for using NSNotificationCenter and kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification to detect expired tokens?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I'm migrating some old Crashlytics code that used the now-deprecated

`[FIRInstanceID instanceIDWithHandler:]` method to use the new

`[FIRInstallations installationIDWithCompletion:]` method.

Related to that cleanup is the deprecation warning: `'kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification' is deprecated`.

In the past, we had added an observer to `NSNotificationCenter` with that name, in order to be notified when the instanceID expired so we could request a new one.

Is there a similar concept for the new installation IDs? I couldn't find any reference to a replacement in [the relevant Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations#objective-c_3), but I wonder if I'm simply overlooking something?

Comment: The [doc I found re: that notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseinstanceid/api/reference/Constants#/c:@kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification) doesn't say it's deprecated (but I bet you knew that)    Can you post the source of that warning? You'll find it in the log navigator > specific build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went digging around in the Firebase libraries for a more helpful deprecation message. I found this in `FIRInstanceID`:

```
__deprecated_msg("FIRInstanceID is deprecated, please use FIRInstallations for installation "
                 "identifier handling and use FIRMessaging for FCM registration token handling.")
```

After looking in both FIRInstallations.h and FIRMessaging.h, it looks like they've replaced that one notification name with two:

- `FIRMessagingRegistrationTokenRefreshedNotification`
- `FIRInstallationIDDidChangeNotification`

So if you're concerned with the installation identifier changing, it looks like you'd want to add an observer to NSNotificationCenter for `FIRInstallationIDDidChangeNotification`.